# Problem with Javascript toggle divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have this problem that i'm sure is simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a javascript function to toggle a div through pressing a button:

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//jquery functionality for toggling member interaction containers
function toggleInteractContainers(x)
{
    if($('#'+x).is(":hidden"))
    {
        $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
    }else
    {
        $('#'+x).hide();
    }
    $('.interactContainers').hide();
}
//function for adding friends...receives two arguments
function addAsPal(a,b)
{
    //alert("Member with ID:" +a+ "is requesting to be pals with member with ID:" +b);
    var url = "request_as_pal.php";
    var thisRandNum = "<?php echo $thisRandNum; ?>";
    $("#add_pal").text("please wait...").show();
    $.post(url,{request:"requestPal", mem1:a, mem2:b, thisWipit: thisRandNum}, function(data){
    $("#add_pal").html(data).show().fadeOut(12000);
    });
}
</script>
```

My html code is (only part of it as it would be too long):

```
<tr>
    <td height="40" class="ordinary_text_12_blue" align="center">Username:</td>
    <td class="ordinary_text_12"><?php echo $row_user_info ['username'];?></td>
    <td align="right" style="border:none;">
        <a href="#" onclick="return false"
           onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers('add_friend');">
         Add as Pal
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="interactContainers" id="add_friend">                     
    <div align="right">
        <a class="ordinary_text_12" href="#" onclick="return false"
           onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers('add_pal');">
         Cancel&nbsp;
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        &nbsp; Add &nbsp;<?php echo "$firstname $lastname"; ?>&nbsp; as a Pal? &nbsp;
        <a class="ordinary_text_12" href="#" onclick="return false"
           onmousedown="javascript:addAsPal(<?php echo $user_id;?>,<?php echo $user_id2;?>);">
          Yes
        </a>
    </div>                          
</div>
```

If you notice on the 5th line of the above html code, i have

```
onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers('add_friend');
```

This works; change it to this:

```
onmousedown="javascript:toggleInteractContainers('add_pal');
```

It does not work.
Can someone help me figure this out. Thanks.

The css code is(if needed):

```
.interactContainers
{
    margin-left:10px;
    position:relative;
    width:486px;    
    display:none;
    color: #09F;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size: 12px;    
    background-color:#222;
    border:#FFF 1px solid;  
}

.interactionLinksDiv a
{
    background-color:#222;
    display:inline;
    border:#FFF 1px solid;
    padding:7px;
    color:#9F3;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: From your code we do not see a div with id='add_pal' therefore there's no add_pal to hide or show.

Comment: Create a jsFiddle example and we'll adjust your invalid code. Because from the code you've provided we can't deduct the interface process behind it. What should happen on some click? What should be shown/hidden...

Comment: I got help on the problem. Thanks for the replys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqm8C/4/)

i removed the onmousedown and place it into the onclick event. also removed the

`$('.interactContainers').hide();`

let me know if this is what you were looking for.  also from your code we do not see a div with id='add_pal' and therefore there's no add_pal div to hide or show.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I got this script for adding friends and I'm tring to tweak it. New to javascript. The problem was with the div_id in the html that I forgot to change to add_pal. Is there a reason you removed the onmousedown and $('.interactContainers').hide();? With or without works anyway.

Comment: i am not totally sure how you want the hyperlink to behave but it just seems redundant to return false on an onclick event and also have onmousedown, but if it works then it works.  plz rep. have a good day.